# Attachement as html

Tags: email, javabeans, lotus-notes, email-attachments, mailto

I want to create a support button in a Java application which should send an e-mail to the support e-mail address with some attachments.

The problem is that the mail server is variable for different users, therefore I cannot use the `JavaMail API` because I cannot set the server. I am left with the basic `mailTo` feature, with the following parameters:

```
mailTo:email@domain.com?subject=TEST%20SUBJECT&body=TEST%20BODY
```

This command will open the default e-mail service(Lotus Notes) on the user's PC with the content of the e-mail already formatted.

I also want to add an attachment to the e-mail, but since `mailTo` does not allow it, the only option left is to add it from the body of the e-mail.

I manually added an attachement to the e-mail body and looking at it's properties I do not have much options to work with:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="timer://simpleTimer?period=1000" />
            <setBody>
                <simple>
                 <Hello from timer at $ header.firedTime } />
                </simple>
            </setBody>
            <to uri="stream:out" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans
```

I am not familiar with web-development, so I thought, are there any tags or is it possible to add some web-scripts to the e-mail body to automatically load the attachement from an absolute path?

I am expecting to be something like:

```
mailTo:email@domain.com?subject=TEST%20SUBJECT&body=<some tag which adds an attachement>
```

or

```
mailTo:email@domain.com?subject=TEST%20SUBJECT&body=some_web_script
```

Comment: If your code is running on the server side, why do you need to know the user's mail server?  With the JavaMail API, you should be able to use any mail server to send your message. It doesn't have to be the same one the user uses.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz The code is running on each user machine. It's a desktop application. The feature would be to press a button and directly open the e-mail service ( Lotus Notes) with the support e-mail completed and with the log files zipped and added as an attachement  to that e-mail.

Comment: Do you really have to open it in the UI?  You could use the Notes Java classes to just send it without any user interaction.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz As a last option, yeah, but if that would require to get some executable locations from the lotus notes installation, it probably wouldn't be a good solution (because of the variable environment)

Comment: Yes, true. That's not easy to do when you're not in control of the environment. It's sometimes not even easy when you are. My recollection, though, is that there's no support for attachments in the Notes Client's implementation of the mailto URI. I once had to write a little custom Domino web app that my code could POST a form with attachment into so the WebQuerySave agent could send the email. That requires Domino HTTP to be running in a known location, though.